# permanently changing screen resolution

Tags: screen

I have to readjust my screen resolution every time I restart my laptop. Is there a way to permanently change it to what I want?

I have been using xrandr to change it temporarily.

Comment: read this it might help for setting us ATI video cards  

http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Jaunty_Installation_Guide

Comment: When I click on the link, it says there is no text to be shown. Also, I have a GEFORCE graphics card

Comment: Link is updated

Answer (score 0):

So this worked for me:

sudo -i
cd /etc/X11
touch xorg.conf
nano xorg.conf

then in the simple nano editor, write (or just paste) this:

Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Configured Video Device"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Default Screen"
        Monitor         "Configured Monitor"
        Device          "Configured Video Device"

```
    SubSection "Display"

      Modes "1280x800"

    EndSubSection
```

EndSection

then save the file using Ctrl+O, then quit Ctrl+x;